# Calling [Authorize] web api actions from ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In order to secure my web api, I have added a `[Authorize]` before action declaration in the following way:

```
[Route("api/getvPaymentDues")]
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
        public dynamic getData()
        {

            var vPaymentDues = (from recordset in db.vPaymentDues
                                select new DTOvPaymentDue
                                {
                                    UserName = recordset.UserName,
                                    FullName = recordset.FullName,
                                    ContactNum = recordset.ContactNum,
                                    Address = recordset.Address,
                                    AreaName = recordset.AreaName,
                                    ColonyName = recordset.ColonyName,
                                    PackageName = recordset.PackageName,
                                    LastRenewDate = recordset.LastRenewDate,
                                    PackageExpiryDate = recordset.PackageExpiryDate,
                                    InvoiceAmount = recordset.InvoiceAmount,
                                    ReceivedAmount = recordset.ReceivedAmount,
                                    DueInDays = recordset.DueInDays
                            });
            return new { data = vPaymentDues };
        }
```

When I call the api as `localhost/api/getvPaymentDues` it is correctly saying that `{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}`

My question is how to send values in the request (when done from ajax) for my web api to get Authorized?

Comment: That depends on how you've setup your authentication. In any case, you'd need to have the API authenticate itself (or generate a token for it), and have it pass the token in with the request: typically via headers for API requests.

Comment: You need to implement authentication to your api. I suggest you go with bearer token as it fits web api well. I like this typ of implementation, have a look: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

I have added Identity Authentication in my application (authorized by cookies). this solved my issue.

When the user logs in, there is a cookie saved in the local system and (during its lifetime) it is making sure the api call is getting authenticated.

not a full fledged solution, but solves my current purpose.